# Convert LPTSTR to string or char * to be written to a file

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to convert LPTSTR to string or char * to be able to write it to file using ofstream.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342772/lptstr-to-char

Comment: Sorry did not appear in search results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most solutions presented in the other threads unnecessarily convert to an obsolete encoding instead of an Unicode encoding. Simply use `reinterpret_cast<const char*>` to write UTF-16 files, or convert to UTF-8 using `WideCharToMultiByte`.

To depart a bit from the question, using `LPTSTR` instead of `LPWSTR` doesn't make much sense nowadays since the old 9x series of Windows is completely obsolete and unsupported. Simply use `LPWSTR` and the accompanying "wide character" (i.e., UTF-16 code unit) types like `WCHAR` or `wchar_t` everywhere.

Here is an example that (I hope) writes UTF-16 or UTF-32 (the latter on Linux/OS X):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::ofstream stream("test.txt");  // better use L"test.txt" on Windows if possible
  std::wstring string = L"Test\n";
  stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(string.data()), string.size() * sizeof(wchar_t));
}
```

Comment: TTBOMK, it's not guaranteed that `wofstream` will write UTF-16. IIRC, the Dinkumware implementation will write (and read, FTM) UTF-8.

Comment: @sbi: Yes, I already noticed that on Linux. C++ streams just suck. To write UTF-16 reliably, you really seem to need to use an `ofstream` to prevent the brain-dead char conversion of C++, and use `reinterpret_cast`. If the Dinkumware library uses UTF-8, fine, at least not some completely insane choice like Windows-1252.

Answer (score 3):

Use [T2A](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3(VS.80).aspx) macro for that.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, `LPTSTTR` might point to a `char` string or a `wchar_t` string, depending on a preprocessor directive. If that's right, then you need to switch between `std::ofstream` and `std::wofstream`, depending on that preprocessor directive.
Have a look at *[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171461/c-arguments-to-main/3171513#3171513)*. It deals with switching between console streams, depending on `TCHAR`, but the scheme is easily adapted to be used with file streams as well.